# Cylindrical integral transformations

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Came across the following integral today:$$\int_{\rho=0}^R \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{z=0}^H \frac{\rho d\rho d\phi dz}{z^2+R^2+\rho^2-2R\rho\cos(\phi)}$$

Here is my try: First we convert this to straightforward cartesian coordinates, which changes the integral to $$\int_{-R}^R \int_{-R}^R\int_0^H \frac{dx dy dz}{z^2+y^2+(R-x)^2}$$ Now if we change the variables $(x,y,z) \to (R-x,y,z)$, we can simply turn the integral into $$\int_{-R}^R \int_{-R}^R\int_0^H \frac{dx dy dz}{z^2+y^2+x^2}$$ Basically the Jacobian is $-1$ and the limits of $x$ simply get interchanged, thereby nullifying the effect of the $-1$. Now changing this back to cylindrical coordinates, we get $$\int_{\rho=0}^R \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{z=0}^H \frac{\rho d\rho d\phi dz}{z^2+\rho^2}$$ which can be evaluated without much difficulty to $$2\pi H\left[\frac RH\tan^{-1}\left(\frac HR\right)+\frac 12\ln\left(1+\frac{R^2}{H^2}\right)\right]$$ But this is not the answer given. THe naswer that is given is $$\pi H\left[1+\frac{2R}H-\sqrt{1+\frac{4R^2}{H^2}}+\ln\left(\frac12\left[1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4R^2}{H^2}}\right]\right)\right]$$
I know that i haven't made any mistake in the evaluation of the final integral in cylindrical coordinates. So, my mistake lies in the substitutions I am performing. Could someone point out where in the substitution I am going wrong, and suggest the correct substitution?

Comment: When you use Cartesian coordintes, what you get is$$\int_{-R}^R\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_0^H\frac{\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz}{z^2+y^2+(R-x)^2}.$$

Comment: Sir, I am a bit weak about limits when it comes to transformation, could you elaborate a bit upon why the limits become $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$? Also, I noticed that I have made a mistake in the question I posted, the limits I had in mind for x and y in Cartesian coordinates were -R and R which I wrongly wrote as 0 and R. I have edited in the mobile version of stack exchange but can't view my edits yet. Please take that into consideration.

Comment: Because you don't integrate across a rectangle, but across a cylinder

Comment: When $\rho$ goes from $0$ to $R$ and $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, the numbers of the form $(\rho\cos\phi,\rho\sin\phi)$ form the disc centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $R$, not the rectangle $[-R,R]\times[-R,R]$. And, in order to describe that disc in Cartesian coordinates, one possibility is that $x$ goes from $-R$ to $R$ and that, for each such $x$, $y$ goes from $-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$.

Comment: So basically when I do the substitution R-x to x, the limits of y will change to something else, right? Something like $\pm \sqrt{R^2-(R-x)^2}$. In that case, how should I evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of an evaluation in cylindrical coordinates:

After the substitutions $\rho = R r$ and $z = R u$ the integral takes the form
$$ I \equiv R  \int \limits_0^{H/R} \mathrm{d} u \int \limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}r \int \limits_0^{2 \pi} \mathrm{d} \phi \, \frac{r}{u^2 + 1 +r^2 - 2 r \cos(\phi)} \, . $$
The integral over $\phi$ can be evaluated using the residue theorem (the method is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_3_%E2%80%93_trigonometric_integrals)) or a [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). The result is
$$ I = 2 \pi R \int \limits_0^{H/R} \mathrm{d} u \int \limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}r \, \frac{r}{\sqrt{(u^2 + 1 + r^2)^2 - 4 r^2}} \, .$$
Now let $t = r^2$, rewrite the denominator (by completing the square) and recognise the derivative of the inverse hyperbolic sine:
\begin{align}
I &= \pi R \int \limits_0^{H/R} \mathrm{d} u \int \limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}t \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{(t + u^2 - 1)^2 + 4 u^2}} \\
&= \pi R \int \limits_0^{H/R} \mathrm{d} u \left[\operatorname{arsinh} \left(\frac{u}{2}\right) - \operatorname{arsinh} \left(\frac{u^2-1}{2 u}\right)\right] \, .
\end{align}
Substitute $u = 2 v$, introduce $\alpha \equiv \frac{H}{2 R}$, use the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine) of $\operatorname{arsinh}$ in terms of the logarithm and simplify the resulting expression to arrive at
$$ I = 2 \pi R \int \limits_0^\alpha \mathrm{d} v \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+v^{-2}}}{2}\right) \, . $$
Finally, integration by parts yields
\begin{align} 
I &= 2 \pi R \left\{ \left[v \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+v^{-2}}}{2}\right) \right]_{v=0}^{v=\alpha} + \int \limits_0^\alpha \mathrm{d} v \frac{v}{(1+\sqrt{1+v^{-2}})\sqrt{1+v^{-2}} \, v^3} \right\} \\
&= 2 \pi R \left\{ \alpha \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^{-2}}}{2}\right) + \int \limits_0^\alpha \mathrm{d} v \frac{1}{(v+\sqrt{1+v^2})\sqrt{1+v^2}} \right\} \\
&= 2 \pi R \left\{ \alpha \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^{-2}}}{2}\right) + \left[ - \frac{1}{v+\sqrt{1+v^2}} \right]_{v=0}^{v=\alpha}\right\} \\
&= 2 \pi R \alpha \left[1 + \alpha^{-1} - \sqrt{1+\alpha^{-2}} + \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^{-2}}}{2}\right) \right] \\
&= \pi H  \left[1 + \frac{2R}{H} - \sqrt{1+ \frac{4 R^2}{H^2}} + \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\left\{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4 R^2}{H^2}}\right\}\right) \right] \, ,
\end{align}
which agrees with your result.